# How can I migrate application from Grails 2.1.2 to Grails 2.3.5?

Tags: rest, events, grails, version, upgrade

I have 3 applications developed with Grails 2.1.2, with 15+ controllers and 200+ views per application. I need to migrate all these applications (one by one) to the newest released version of Grails 2.3.5, as I want to use REST/event features supported in new version. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is  [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html) for upgrade.

Comment: As I know, link-only answers is poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from 2.2.2 to 2.3.4 for us was *fairly* painless. We followed the instructions [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html), but we stuck with Ivy for dependency resolution (switching to Aether seemed to give us a bit of a headache):

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy"
```

There were a couple of other minor things, like removing the spock plugin (it's now included by default) and changing the version of the tomcat and hibernate plugins (they're now versioned independently), but these are documented.

We have quite good test coverage, so we were pretty confident that we'd catch any problems caused by upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download and put new grails version(2.3.5) in environment variables.
Step 2: Navigate to your project folder using terminal/cmd/whatever.
Step 3: execute `grails upgrade`
Step 4: It will upgrade your project from 2.1.2 to 2.3.5 easily or print errors in case of failure.

and voila you have upgraded your project to grails latest version.